# Cannot start Electron application - missing package.json

Tags: npm, terminal, electron, package.json, npm-start

I'm currently doing a Python project where I want to display my results in an Electron application. I have seen a demo video on YouTube on how to set up Electron on a Mac. The video showed 3 simple steps to be executed in the terminal:

```
git clone https://github.com/electron/electron-quick-start
cd electron-quick-start
npm install && npm start
```

When I first ran the above commands it worked fine for me. I was able to start the Electron application.

But when I tried to re-start the application using the command `npm start` after going into the `electron-quick-start` directory, I am not able to open the application.

I am continuously getting an error message as follows:

```
(base) Viveks-MacBook-Pro:electron-quick-start vivekchowdary$ npm start
npm ERR! path /Users/vivekchowdary/package.json
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/vivekchowdary/package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent 

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/vivekchowdary/.npm/_logs/2019-04-19T12_55_01_157Z-debug.log
(base) Viveks-MacBook-Pro:electron-quick-start vivekchowdary$
```

I don't know what it means? But I just want to open the Electron application.

Comment: Maybe your terminal is not in the `electron-quick-start` folder.

Comment: @LeonardoBuscemi, It is in that library only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the error message states, the file `package.json` cannot be found.

One possible reason is that the terminal is not in the correct project folder and that you need to `cd` into the folder before running `npm start`.

If you `cd` to any folder that has no `package.json` (and whose parent folders don't have a `package.json`) and run `npm start`, you'll be presented with this error message.

Your specific file path seems to indicate that you ran `npm start` from your home folder, not the project folder that contains `package.json`.

Answer (score 0):

I got a similar issue and I fixed it by creating the files it was asking for as well as a basic package.json file that my compiler generated for me