# Electron --serve fails on missing package.json

Tags: node.js, angular, electron, ionic4

I have a strange issue working on PoC application. It is an Electron app using Angular 7 and Ionic 4. It's very simple, just two routes, one fake service and not much going on there.

In `package.json` I have defined following scripts:

```
"electron:serve": "electron . --serve",
"electron:transpile": "webpack ./electron/src/main.ts --config ./electron/webpack.electron.config.js",
"build:electron": "npm run electron:transpile && npm run build:web && electron-builder build"
```

Folder structure is as follows:

```
poc-client
+- dist
   +- ...
+- electron
   +- dist
   +- src
   +- tsconfig.json
   +- webpack.electron.config.js
+- src
   +- ...
+- package.json
```

Now wen I run `build:electron` it builds the app, generates executable in dist folder and everything works as expected. But when I run `electron:serve` Electron starts but I'll get the following error:

[image: Error]

Console in VS Code shows no error when running the script neither there are any issues shown in Chromium Dev Tools. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55762367/cannot-start-electron-application-missing-package-json), but it's not the case, I tried adding fake `package.json` to electron folder but with no effect. I'm running out of ideas, what to do.

Answer (score 1):

it looks like you are serving in your dist directory but looking for a package.json file in your root directory.

Comment: I don't see a reason why would app from dist require package.json

Comment: I am not saying it should, but from the screenshot with the error message it looks like it is doing just that